# Is there a way to automatically space buttons in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a range of buttons which I would like to space evenly across my nav bar. I could get the size of each button and work it out but I wonder is there a way of working this out automatically and setting these widths at as the page loads.
At the minute I have 5 buttons and an input field and would like to make these span a 800px div.

HTML:

```
<div class="nav">
                <div class="nav_btn">HOME</div>
                <div class="nav_btn">NEW IN</div>
                <div class="nav_btn_drop_down">CLOTHING</div>
                <div class="nav_btn_drop_down">ACCESSORIES</div>
                <div class="nav_btn_drop_down">SHOP BY BRAND</div>
                <div class="nav_btn"><form action="" method="POST"><input type="text" placeholder="Search..." /></form></div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav{
    height:50px;
    color:blue;
}
.nav_btn,.nav_btn_drop_down{
    float:left;
    color:#78f7fa;
}
```

Comment: If you need to space them evenly - why're u floating them left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this trick using `display:table-cell` instead of `float`:

```
.nav_btn, .nav_btn_drop_down{
    display:table-cell;
    width:1%;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Check this demo **http://jsfiddle.net/xveV4/10/**

Comment: wow that was really straight forward, didn't think of using display:table-cell;

Answer (score 1):

I think `padding` would solve your problem:

```
.nav_btn,.nav_btn_drop_down{
    float:left;
    color:#78f7fa;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dLaC2/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.  You could always use percentages for the width of each nav_btn/nav_btn_drop_down.

```
.nav{
    height:50px;
    color:blue;
}
.nav_btn,.nav_btn_drop_down{
    float:left;
    color:#78f7fa;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:16.667%
}
```

Each item in your nav is itemcount/100 in width ~= 16.667%

See fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/t9t2D/